# How do you hand off and rename a custodial NEAR account to a user?

Tags: nearprotocol, near

A toy example:

1. The application `NFTApp` created a new account `throwaway.near` for a new user and minted some NFTs into it.  `NFTApp` has the only full access key to `throwaway.near`. The user doesn't even know what a seed phrase is.
2. At a later time, the user decides they want to take possession of this account and its contents but name it `keeper.near`.  Maybe they have created `keeper.near` previously or maybe they create it fresh as part of this process. Either way, the user controls the only full access key to `keeper.near`.
3. `NFTApp` then deletes `throwaway.near` and recovers the storage tokens from it.

How can we effect this handoff without needing to manually send contents from `throwaway.near` to `keeper.near`?